# Tested SQL query not working in SQL Editor of Apache Superset

Tags: sql-server, apache-superset, pymssql

I am trying to create new dataset via SQL Labs Editor. I have SQL query which is working fine via database manager. However, if I try same query in SQL Lab on Apache Superset it is not working, giving the following error (database I use is Microsoft SQL Server):

> Azure Synapse Error
> mssql error: All your SQL functions need to have an alias on MSSQL. For example: SELECT COUNT(*) AS C1 FROM TABLE1
> This may be triggered by:
> Issue 1002 - The database returned an unexpected error.

This is the query:

```
SELECT cast(I04_OP_DATA as date), I04_OP_RUSIS, SUM(I05_SUMA)
FROM I04_ATH
LEFT JOIN I05_ATD 
ON I04_ATH.I04_KODAS_CH  = I05_ATD.I05_KODAS_CH
GROUP BY cast(I04_OP_DATA as date), I04_OP_RUSIS;
```

Comment: Have you tried aliasing your columns as the error says?

Comment: Sql server doesn't autocreate names for columns containing expressions, and probably this dataset application you use requires proper names. Add alias to all columns like: cast(I04_OP_DATA as date) as alias_name_without_spaces

Comment: Issue 1002 isn't an SQL Server-related error. I think you'll find it's coming from whatever Python library SQLAlchemy is using under the covers, probably something DBAPI-based.

Answer (score 1):

Try providing names for the new variables you create.  For instance this works for me in SQL Server but not Apache Superset SQL Lab:

```
SELECT MAX([my_variable])
FROM my_table
```

But this works on both:

```
SELECT MAX([my_variable]) as X
FROM my_table
```

Though the error message I usually see is "Microsoft SQL Server Error  - no field of name".  I'm running Superset 2.1.0.  FYI there's a Superset discussion on this: https://github.com/apache/superset/discussions/23213

Comment: Thanks Sam, adding alias as you offered indeed helped the case.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT TOP 10000
AVG  (RisOrderId  ) 
FROM dbo.[VW_OrderTable]
```

--> gives 1002 err.

```
SELECT TOP 10000
AVG  (RisOrderId  ) as Average 
FROM dbo.[VW_OrderTable]
```

works fine.

Comment: How is this answer different in essence [from this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76540656/16343464)?